# iText 7 - Regenerate BarCode field created with Adobe

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I come to you because I've a question !

I created a barCode with Adobe Acrobat in a acroform PDF. I can set the new value to the barCode field but I can't generate the new "appearance" with the new value. How can I do that ?

This is how I do for now with no success ... :

```
PdfFormField field = fields.get("QRCODE");
field.setValue(this.generateXMLDataMatrix(),false);
form = form.setNeedAppearances(true);
form.flattenFields();
pdf.close();
```

So for now, I still have the default appearance created in Adobe Acrobat :(

Thank you for you help ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to generate the field appearance manually. Here is an example of how to do it for a QR code one:

```
PdfFormField field = fields.get("QRCODE");
// Get the annotation. If you might have multiple representations of the same field across the document the just iterate over all widgets
PdfWidgetAnnotation annotation = field.getWidgets().get(0);
// This class will help us draw the barcode
BarcodeQRCode qrCode = new BarcodeQRCode(this.generateXMLDataMatrix());
// Get the number of rectangles constituting the barcode
Rectangle size = qrCode.getBarcodeSize();
// Creating a new FormXObject that will become our apperance. Set the dimension(bbox) of the current appearance
PdfFormXObject newAppearance = new PdfFormXObject(annotation.getAppearanceObject(PdfName.N).getAsRectangle(PdfName.BBox));
// Helper class to draw on FormXObject
PdfCanvas barcodeCanvas = new PdfCanvas(newAppearance, pdfDocument);
// Calculating the side of the smaller rectangle in the barcode
float side = Math.min(annotation.getRectangle().toRectangle().getHeight() / size.getHeight(),
        annotation.getRectangle().toRectangle().getWidth() / size.getWidth());
// Draw the barcode on the XObject
qrCode.placeBarcode(barcodeCanvas, ColorConstants.BLACK, side);
// Set appearance to the newly generated one
annotation.setAppearance(PdfName.N, newAppearance.getPdfObject());
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! This how i finally did it :

```
    //Generate BarCodedataMatrix
    BarcodeDataMatrix dataMatrix = new BarcodeDataMatrix();
    //Add code to the BarCodedataMatrix
    dataMatrix.setCode(generateXMLDataMatrix());
    dataMatrix.setOptions(BarcodeDataMatrix.DM_AUTO);
    //Add dataMatrix to PDF
    //Create a canvas for the first page
    PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdf.getFirstPage());
    //Create the PdfFormXObject based on the dataMatrix
    PdfFormXObject object = dataMatrix.createFormXObject(pdf);
    //Add the pdfFormXObject to the canvas at X,Y position
    canvas.addXObject(object,50,660);
```

Comment: This adds the barcode to the page content, not to the field appearance.